Pull all BuildingInsight from Google Solar API within a given parcel area
I am working on a project analyzing the solar potential within a given parcel location. Even though there is only one large building within the area, the Google solar API seems classified the large building into a number of small buildings.
I am wondering if we can extract all building insights within a given GIS boundary area? Is there any efficient way to do this?
Thank you!
I have tried directly calling solar API manually within the area to retrieve building insights for each small rooftop. However the current method is not automated.
